# Is possible run command on different terminal on Github action?

Tags: flask, github, github-actions

1.Currently, I'm building a flask project and I also wrote some unit testing code. Now I would like to run the Unit test on the GitHub action, but it stuck at the ./run stage(./run will turn on the http://127.0.0.1:5000/), and does not run the $pytest command. I know the reason why $pytest will not be executed because the Github Action is running the port  http://127.0.0.1:5000/. In this case, it can not execute any commands after./run. I was wondering can I run $pytest on another terminal in GitHub action? Is this possible?

Here is the output of my github action:

```
Run cd Flask-backend
  cd Flask-backend
  ./run
  pytest 
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.10/x64
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 404-425-256
```

2.Here is my code for yml file:

```
name: UnitTesting
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Python 3
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirement.txt
          
      - name: Run tests with pytest
        run: |
           cd Flask-backend
           ./run
           pytest
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nohup` command to run the flask server in the background instead of running on a different terminal.

```
nohup python app.py
```

Wait for some time after running this command using the `sleep` command and then run your tests.

Comment: But how can I turn off the port If I want to close it ?

Comment: ```kill -9 $(lsof -i :5000 | awk 'FNR > 1 {print $2}')```

Comment: Sorry.. I just tried what you said, it still only run the server. The pytest did not execute  successfully

Comment: Just try with a simple curl to see if the server is accessible and check if there are any errors while running the app in background

Answer (score 1):

I tried it several times but without any success. But there is a simple workaround to test your api locally. I achieved it with a pytest script by using the test_client() from flask package. This client simulates your flask-app.

```
from api import app

# init test_client
app.config['TESTING'] = True
client = app.test_client()

# to test your app
def test_api():
   r = client.get('/your_endpoint')
   assert r.status_code == 200
```

Note that every requests now made directly over the client and the methods which belongs to.
You can find more information here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/